# Obtaining marginal densities from joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm given a joint probability density function of X and Y.

$$f(x, y)=c \mathrm{e}^{-y}|y-x|, \quad y>0 \text { and }-1 \leq x \leq 1$$

After normalizing I obtain $c = \frac{1}{\frac{-2}{e}+3}$. Now I am interested in the marginal densities of X and Y. How do I obtain these? I know to integrate with respect to each of the variables.

Comment: it seems that you know what to do, where are you stuck?

Comment: In particular, what are the bounds on each of the integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

If we want to compute $f_X(x)$, we are fixing the $x$ and we want to integrate over the $y$. Hence we should integrate from $0$ to $\infty$.

If we want to compute $f_Y(y)$, we are fixing the $y$ and we want to integrate over the $x$. Hence we should integrate from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: The problem is that when trying to compute the first one, there is an issue somewhere, due to the absolute value.

Comment: The second one is well-defined, but the first has a problem.

Comment: Split the integral into two parts when $y> x$ and when $y<x$ then.

Answer (score 0):

You have found $c$ by using: $$\begin{align}1&=\iint_{y>0, -1\leq x\leq 1} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x,y)\\[1ex]&= \int_{-1}^1\int_0^\infty c\,
\mathrm e^{−y}
\lvert y−x\rvert~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_0^x c\mathrm e^{-y}(x-y)\mathrm d y+\int_x^\infty c\mathrm e^{-y}(y-x)\mathrm d y\right)~\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Surely you can then see that:

$$f_X(x)=\int_{y>0} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d y\\f_Y(y)=\int_{-1\leq x\leq 1} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x$$

Brought to you by the fact that the supports are seperable.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is with the first integral though, given the limits and the absolute value. I'm not sure how to break it up appropriately to make it solvable.

Comment: Partition the integrals on $y\leq x$ and $y> x$.